# Long Swipe on Tableview cell crashes in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview with edit actions implemented. When swiped left on tablecell, it shows "Options" text and on tap of "Options" it displays alert view with few options. This works perfectly in iPhone

But in iPad this works only if I swipe slowly and just to an extend. If I swipe hard / do long swipe it crashes my app.

It crashes with SIGABART error without catching even if I have Exception break point. Not sure why this is happening. Please advice

Im assuming the issue is with self.present..not sure though

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.addAlertForiPad(alert: alertController)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    public func addAlertForiPad(alert: UIAlertController) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
                popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to remove “DispatchQueue.main.async” from this “addAlertForiPad(alert: UIAlertController)”?

Comment: This worked. Thanks..But may I know the reason for this please? Should I not switch to main thread twice?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the main thread inside the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the cpu/ram usage when you were doing these ? Maybe your ipad is too old and is not able to support a fast scroll in a TableView... And can you send the code who define each cell please, it would be helpfull